# Brakeman exit on warn cross-scripting error unsafe parameter value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang, circleci, cross-site, brakeman

I'm using CircleCI to check for security issues and this is cropping up as an error, though I'm not sure that it is.

This is the line of code that is causing one of the scripting errors:

```
= link_to t(:delete), main_app.board_comment_path(@board, comment), method: :delete
```

Is this a valid security issue? Is there any way for me to make Brakeman accept these parameters as safe? I read up on `--url-safe-methods` but I couldn't figure out a way to make it work.

Used this link as a guide https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/pull/45

Running `bundle exec brakeman -A -q --exit-on-warn`, this is the error report:

```
+BRAKEMAN REPORT+

Application path: ****
Rails version: 4.2.2
Brakeman version: 3.0.4
Started at 2015-06-26 14:10:14 -0700
Duration: 1.8311 seconds
Checks run: BasicAuth, ContentTag, CreateWith, CrossSiteScripting, DefaultRoutes, Deserialize, DetailedExceptions, DigestDoS, EscapeFunction, Evaluation, Execute, FileAccess, FileDisclosure, FilterSkipping, ForgerySetting, HeaderDoS, I18nXSS, JRubyXML, JSONEncoding, JSONParsing, LinkTo, LinkToHref, MailTo, MassAssignment, ModelAttrAccessible, ModelAttributes, ModelSerialize, NestedAttributes, NumberToCurrency, QuoteTableName, Redirect, RegexDoS, Render, RenderDoS, RenderInline, ResponseSplitting, SQL, SQLCVEs, SSLVerify, SafeBufferManipulation, SanitizeMethods, SelectTag, SelectVulnerability, Send, SendFile, SessionSettings, SimpleFormat, SingleQuotes, SkipBeforeFilter, StripTags, SymbolDoS, SymbolDoSCVE, TranslateBug, UnsafeReflection, UnscopedFind, ValidationRegex, WithoutProtection, XMLDoS, YAMLParsing


+SUMMARY+

+-------------------+-------+
| Scanned/Reported  | Total |
+-------------------+-------+
| Controllers       | 23    |
| Models            | 9     |
| Templates         | 53    |
| Errors            | 0     |
| Security Warnings | 2 (0) |
+-------------------+-------+

+----------------------+-------+
| Warning Type         | Total |
+----------------------+-------+
| Cross Site Scripting | 2     |
+----------------------+-------+


View Warnings:

+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------->>
| Confidence | Template                                                         | Warning Type         | Message            >>
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------->>
| Medium     | boards/show (BoardsController#show) | Cross Site Scripting | Unsafe parameter va>>
| Medium     | boards/show (BoardsController#show) | Cross Site Scripting | Unsafe parameter va>>
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------->>
```

Comment: The report is truncated (The "Unsafe parameter va .."), can you please try running brakeman again, passing it the flag `-f csv` or `-f tabs`? Then please add the complete report line to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (almost certainly) a false positive, assuming `board_comment_path` returns a path.

The reason Brakeman warns about URLs in `link_to` is because it is possible to set URLs like `javascript:dangerous_stuff_here()`. A common example would be user profiles linking to a user's website.

`--url-safe-methods` only applies to methods wrapping input to `link_to`. For example, `link_to 'stuff', safe_url(some_input)`.

However, after https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/pull/674 Brakeman will stop warning about path helpers in URLs and also expand `--safe-methods`/`--url-safe-methods` to match all types of methods.